# C++ Builder XE2 - is it possible to debug vcl data library?

Tags: debugging, static-libraries, vcl, built-in, c++builder-xe2

I am using method TParams::ParamByName when working with SQL database. Source code of this method is placed in directory c:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\source\data in file Data.DB.pas. Is it possible to debug source code of this unit? Currently I am able to debug data unit only using asembler window (without viewing commands defined in higher programming laguages). VCL is statically linked to the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the Project Options.

There is no need to set `Use debug .dcus` under `Delphi Compiler` > `Compiling` if your projects contains only C++ & C files (see Remy Lebeau answer).

Disable `Link with Dynamic RTL` under `C++ Linker`.

Disable `Link with Runtime Packages` under `Packages` > `Runtime Packages`.

If your project (lets name it Project1) was upgraded from older versions of development environment (C++ Builder XE and older), delete parameter `Directories & Conditionals` -> `Library Path` from all nodes (All Configurations, All Configuration - 32-bit Windows Platform, Debug Configuration, ...) except paths specific for this particular project. Open second instance of C++ Builder XE2. Click `File` -> `New` -> `VCL Forms Application`. Right click on project in Project Manager and select `Options`. Navigate to `Directories & Conditionals` -> `Library path`. Copy paths from all nodes to their counterparts in Project1.

Answer (score 4):

Go into the Project Options.

Enable `Use debug .dcus` under `Delphi Compiler > Compiling`.

Disable `Link with Dynamic RTL` under `C++ Linker`.

Disable `Link with Runtime Packages` under `Packages > Runtime Packages`.

You will then be able to step into the VCL/RTL source code.

Comment: Doesn't function. I can see names of methods in assembler code, but when open *.pas source code, there no blue dots so I can't set breakpoints.

Comment: Can the reason be that we didnt buy RAD Studio only C++ Builder XE2?

Comment: No. This should work fine whether you have Delphi installed or not. If this is still not working correctly then you probably don't have your search paths configured correctly so the IDE can find the VCL source code and debug library binaries.

Comment: Now I found its only problem of XE2 IDE. C++ Builder XE functions correctly.

Comment: But problem remains only on old project converted from BCB6 to XE2. Newly created project in XE2 hasnt any difficulties with debugging VCL.