Parameter values are shown incorrectly when debugging VCL from C++ Builder 11/12
When developing a GUI project in C++ Builder VCL, I often need to debug VCL itself to understand why things do not work the way I expect. Now I'm upgrading my project to C++ Builder 11 and I've found that debugging VCL is broken. When stepping into some Pascal code from C++ project, the variables/parameters show incorrect values in debugger. (And my upgraded project fails deep in VCL, so I need to debug it.)
I've encountered the problem with my licensed C++ Builder 11 Version 28.0.46141.0937. But I was able to reproduce the problem with a trial version of latest 12.1 too.
In the screenshot below, you can see a callstack from a default unmodified Windows VCL Application project. In the callstack the this/Self "parameter" should have the same value in all top three levels. Yet it differs between C++ (this in TForm5::TForm5 and TForm::TForm) and Pascal (Self in TCustomForm::Create). Similarly, the top four levels should feature a pointer to the same Application object (Self in TApplication::CreateForm, AOwner in TCustomForm::Create – but also in TForm and TForm5 constructors, which shown strange __ctor_flag instead of expected AOwner).

The screenshot is for the default (clang?) compiler. The same problem occurs however with the "classic" (bcc?) compiler – except the __ctor_flag problem does not occur. With 64-bit compiler, I'm not able to debug VCL at all (the debugger does not step into it).
Correct are the values in C++ calls (I've verified that they point to the actual object data). The Pascal values are just rubbish. They even change as I step through the Pascal code (within the same method). Also the problem does not occur for all Pascal methods. But I wasn't able to identify, if there's any pattern so far (though virtual method might be a factor here).
Note that this is not about the Self pointer only. The value of Self affects debugging all class fields. So once in the affected Pascal code, all fields values show garbage only.

The code (though that's just the default project template, I haven't modified anything):
Project?.cpp:
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
USEFORM("Unit5.cpp", Form5);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm5), &Form5);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unit5.cpp:
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit5.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm5 *Form5;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm5::TForm5(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

The screenshot and code is from 11.2. But I've tried 12 trial too and the same problem occurs.

The following screenshot shows the expected and correct callstack from old C++ Builder XE6 for its own default VCL Forms Application project.


Reproduction steps:

I've created fresh Windows VM on AWS EC2 (Windows Server 2022 Base, c5.2xlarge) – Though the problem happens on any machine I've tried it on (VM or not)

No modification in Windows

Downloaded https://altd.embarcadero.com/download/radstudio/11.0/RADStudio_11_2_10937a.iso (11.2) or https://altd.embarcadero.com/download/radstudio/12.0/RADStudio_12_1_esd_61_7529b.exe (12.1)

Executed installation

Checked C++ Builder, unchecked Delphi, no other change

Executed C++ Builder

File > New > Windows VCL Application

No modification to source code

Turned off Link with Dynamic RTL and Link with Runtime Packages (to enable VCL debugging, as per for example C++ Builder XE2 - is it possible to debug vcl data library?)
I've also tried turning on Delphi Compiler > Compiling > Use debug dcus (without any noticeable effect)

Stepped into:
_tWinMain
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm5), &Form5);
Instance.Create(Self);
TForm(Owner)
TCustomForm(AOwner)


Resulting Call Stack window attached



Is debugging VCL in C++ Builder 11/12 really broken? Can it be fixed with some settings? Or am I doing something wrong?
I did submit RSS-903 on Embarcadero Quality Portal weeks ago. No response. But I cannot imagine that it really does not work at all. I wonder how others use C++ Builder 11/12. To me, it's useless without ability to debug VCL.

You should contact Embarcadero directly for support.

@RemyLebeau I did submit RSS-903 on Embarcadero Quality Portal weeks ago. No response. But I cannot imagine that it really does not work at all. I wonder how others use C++ Builder 11/12. To me, it's useless without ability to debug VCL.

I am use 12.1, and I'm able to step into the VCL source code only with the 32bit compilers (both classic and clang).  The 64bit debugger has always had problems, so its not surprising you are having issues with it.

Are you compiling for 64bit (legacy) or 64bit Modern? They are separate platforms with separate compilers. Also, do you have "Use debug dcus" enabled to step into VCL sources? Your steps to reproduce seem to be missing some steps. Also, the Self pointer inside TApplication.CreateForm() being different from the AOwner pointer inside of TCustomForm.Create() makes sense, since they should be pointing at different areas of the TApplication object due to inheritance. AOwner points at the TComponent portion of the object, not the base address where Self is pointing at.

@RemyLebeau Thanks for some ideas to try. 1) I'm primarily interested in 32-bit for now (though in long term, I'm indeed upgrading to 11 for 64-bit support). 2) I didn't have "debug dcus" enabled. Though enabling it did not change anything. I can step into VCL even without that option (as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/11432880/850848). And the parameter values problem is the same both with the option on or off. And both with classic compiler on and off (all 4 combinations). So I do not think my steps are missing anything. I've reproduced the problem numerous times using them. Cannot you?


Regarding the pointer values difference due to the inheritance: Did something change in new versions of C++ Builder? Because I believe that in the old versions, the VCL object inheritance was always additive and single-ancestor. So the pointers never changed. And even if they did, the pointers would have to be nearby, right? What 03364860 and 0135FBE4 are not at all. – I appreciate your attention.


@RemyLebeau I've further verified that the C++ pointers are the correct ones (what I've expected from the beginning). I've update the question with few more information.
